# How do I find a cardboard point tracker (and what is it called)?

Tags: tools, product-identification

I need numbered counters for my game. Often I'm using dice, but going up and down by one takes time to search for the other face, and it might roll.

So I tried to find some cardboard counters: I imagined two discs attached to each other such that the front one is hiding all numbers of the lower one except for one and then beeing able to turn the discs to change the shown number.

I'm sure I've seen these things, but on Amazon and eBay I just get these mechanical counters which go up to 1000 and can only go in one direction and anyway are too big, or a lot of app suggestions which I don't like so much.

What is the name of these type of counters and where do I get them?

> Community guidance: Please **do not** just link arbitrary web stores. Provide comprehensive answers that both identify the product & give general guidance that may be applicable across the globe.

Comment: Indeed this goes into the right direction, since I intend to buy about 10 of them the price is a little high and cardboard would be enough.

Comment: I've edited this to be a product identification because you have a specific solution in mind, but just need a more thorough identification for it. If you wanted to have arbitrary solutions recommended to you, that's no longer quite our thing since recommendations of tools were ruled off topic a while back -- but if you're having trouble tracking something in a specific game, you can ask experts of that game what an effective way to handle your problem is. (In a separate question.)

Comment: I agree with everything you say except that I don't have any game in mind except my homebrewed ones.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is a product recommendation in disguise.

Comment: @seven From what I could tell it was not, but it's certainly being treated that way by answers so I don't object to closing it. That's disappointing nobody engaged in the actual identification thing nor general purchase advice.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think the problem is that it isn't quite an ID question—it is about a generally-described *desired* thing rather than asking for the ID of something concrete. Then it asks where to get them, which brings the underlying desire for shopping help to the surface in plain terms. It got answers in kind. I think it would have pulled different answers if it had been directly and only an ID question.

Comment: Or alternately a question that's just asking for a solution to a specific problem (showing up in game design for a homebrew, or in an existing popular game) but if was just "I need to track numbers and dice don't work" that'd be far too broad (there's dozens of practical ways to track numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Make your own.

As an example, see the "Combat Computer" from [Dragon 74](http://www.annarchive.com/files/Drmg074.pdf) (last 2 pages, although check out the character creation program written in Basic in the middle).

All you need is a piece of cardboard, something to write with and a split thumb tack, all available for less than $1 at your local newsagent. Cut one ring bigger than the other, write numbers on the big ring, put an arrow on the small ring, push the split tack through the middle and voila!

Comment: For a little more sophistication, any graphic editor has the tools to create the window disk and the background part (I'd recommend Inkscape as its tools are especially good for this kind of task).  Print the result, and glue to light card stock (or print directly on the card stock, if your printer can handle it), cut out, and fasten at the center so they turn with a little friction -- done!

Answer (score 1):

I find a French website about the Magic card game counter [Google translated here](https://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smfcorp.net%2Fmtg-articles-2225-les-compteurs-de-points-de-vie.html&edit-text=), it list different method

If you search about Magic the Gathering counter, you will find lots of subject on the matter, there is even apps for that

Answer (score -1):

### Make your own

A metal ruler and a magnetic button (or small fridge magnet).

A small abacus or similar (might be available from budget stores).

A repurposed game. For example [Connect 4](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=connect+4+game&num=20&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHZL_enNZ689NZ689&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaiIiDg5TPAhWFjz4KHXm1Ab4Q_AUICCgB&biw=1307&bih=957) or [3D tic tac toe](http://www.motherearthnews.com/diy/3d-tic-tac-toe-zmaz81jfzraw.aspx).

A small whiteboard, something like the [Pathfinder intiative tracker](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9fkg?Pathfinder-Combat-Pad) or the [Alea Tools tracker](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/aleatools/alea-tools-rpg-initiative-board?ref=discovery). I use something like this on a whiteboard I bought from a stationery shop.

A deck of cards, already sorted. Each round, turn over the next card.

Pegs or clips along the top of your DMS screen or along the edge of a game box. As seen [here at roleplayingtips.com](http://roleplayingtips.com/images/438-GM-Screentop-Tracker-01.jpg) and [here at SkylandGames](https://skylandgames.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/img_1509.jpg).

Answer (score -2):

I found [these discs](https://www.spielematerial.de/en/game-components/blankomaterial/selection-disc.html) at spielematerial which you could write numbers on and point the arrows at. They seem to be called "selection discs" but I think that is probably a translation from the German.